# Auto Rig Pro Export to GLTF

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I'm trying to export a model with miximo animation as a glTF embedded.  Character is rigged & skinned. Animation is loaded correctly. However, when I export via Auto Rig Pro export to glTF, I get an empty file and it is not loading in a glTF viewer.

I can export the model fine, which compiles to a 1400 kb sized glTF file. However when I try to select the armature along with the model, I only get 8k file size.

Validation report

```
Format: glTF 2.0
Generator: Khronos glTF Blender I/O v3.5.30
Stats:
0 draw calls
1 animations
0 materials
0 vertices
0 triangles
Extensions:
None
Report generated byKhronosGroup/glTF-Validator 2.0.0-dev.3.9.

Info    Message    Pointer
NODE_EMPTY    Empty node encountered.    /nodes/0
```

Anyone coming across the same issue?

Comment: Might be worth submitting a bug report. You can do this on the Preferences > Addon entry for the Gltf addon. There's a 'Report a Bug' button there.

Comment: Working with the Auto Rig Pro team to figure out what's going on. Will follow up. Hopefully this is an isolated incident due to my inexperience and not a global issue.